# What was Rose's Job?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

We know she appears to be an engineer for the resistance.

> Rose: I work behind pipes all day

However, when Finn meets her she appears to be on guard duty to stop people from using the escape pods to abandon ship.

> Rose: Can you believe I've had to stun three people already today?

Also when she's piloting the salt speeder she seems to do a pretty good job of staying alive and outlives most of the actual pilots.

With all this it appears that she is more than just an engineer, do we know what her actual job was?

---

<sup>Disclaimer: All quotes are from memory so they might not be 100% accurate.</sup>

Comment: Her job was to find Fin something to do in the movie...

Comment: @Loki If you're going down that route she also found BB-8, Poe and pretty much the whole resistance something to do until they got onto Crait.

Comment: To be fair, she didn't really outlive most of the 'actual' pilots, as most of the snubfighter pilots were already dead.  As a flight technician, she likely had more small craft experience than most of the survivors, and likely wold have found herself serving as a transport pilot had she been on board for the evacuation.

Comment: @Jeff Maybe but she wasn't in "pilot uniform" and the only ones that seemed not to be were Finn and Poe

Comment: Rose was not in a flight suit because she hadn't been geared up as a pilot when she left the cruiser.  Since she left the cruiser, she hadn't had a chance to change, and was still wearing the same clothes she escaped the First Order in.  The rest of the speeder pilots were wearing flightsuits, likely because they had just finished flying transports (or serving as copilots for them, or whatever).

Comment: I saw 'stun people who are trying to abandon ship' more as a hobby than a job. If the Resistance wanted her to guard the escape pods, they would have given her a blaster.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rose is a **Support Engineer** and **Flight Technician**. It's her job to keep the Resistance's ships and technology working properly.

Per the film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary)

> Rose spends most of her time deep in the inner workings of starships,
>   her mastery of technology essential to keeping the rickety vessels of
>   the Resistance operational. She is the first to admit that her people
>   skills need work.

and

> A HARDWORKING member of the Resistance support crew, Rose Tico has
>   hated the First Order since she was a child.

and

> **FLIGHT TECHNICIAN**
>
> *Rose is an imaginative mechanic. Her innovations  include a baffle system that makes the Resistance’s  bombers harder to detect by enemy
>   sensors.*

---

Her [official bio](http://www.starwars.com/databank/rose-tico) on the Starwars.com page describes her as ***Maintenance* Technician**

> **ROSE TICO**
>
> *A maintenance tech with a talent for tinkering, Rose Tico joined the Resistance with her sister Paige after the First Order devastated her
>   home system. A chance encounter with Finn pushes her onto the front
>   lines of the new galactic civil war.*

And her sister refers to her as a **Flight Engineer** in [Star Wars: Bomber Command](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Jedi:_Bomber_Command)

[image]

Comment: So presumably as a flight technician she would have had to test the ships and knowing them inside out gives her a decent flying ability. I suppose the guard duty can be passed off as the resistance being low on members.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Elsewhere in the visual dictionary it points out that a) The Resistance doesn't have any infantry, just trained support personnel who multi-skill as infantry when needed and b) That many support staff are also trained pilots

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't think she was on official guard duty. I think she was working down there and noticed people trying to use the pods.

Comment: About that "imaginative mechanic" bit: you can see this in the movie when everyone else was asserting "tracking through hyperspace is impossible", but she (and Finn too) immediately went right to how it in fact could be possible. It seems like they are trying to set her up as the Star Wars equivalent of Trek's Scotty going forward.